# Bootstrap 5 rounded-circle class not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
body {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

hr {
    border: 1.5px solid #0b5ed7
}

.crd {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
    background: #0b5ed7;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.card img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title: </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
<section class="bg-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white py-5">
        <h2 class="display-6">100's of Companies have Switched to Our Company</h2>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
                      <img src="./assets/favicon-Icon Only [G]_76x76.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" />
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">John Doe</p>
                        <p>Sit occaecat amet aute duis occaecat irure ea. Nostrud minim aliqua esse amet. Culpa laborum voluptate culpa excepteur in in ullamco velit aliqua.
  
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-warning">
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Bootstrap 5 to make a website and I am currently using it to make a course that displays cards of different people's reviews, but I am trying to use the rounded-circle class on an image but it isn't working, no circle appears around the image. There is supposed to be a rounded circle around the image but for some reason it's not appearing.

This is what it currently looks like [image]

This is what it's supposed to look like [image]

### Code

#### Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title: </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
<section class="bg-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white py-5">
        <h2 class="display-6">100's of Companies have Switched to Our Company</h2>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
                      <img src="./assets/favicon-Icon Only [G]_76x76.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" />
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">John Doe</p>
                        <p>Sit occaecat amet aute duis occaecat irure ea. Nostrud minim aliqua esse amet. Culpa laborum voluptate culpa excepteur in in ullamco velit aliqua.
  
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-warning">
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Index.css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
body {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

hr {
    border: 1.5px solid #0b5ed7
}

.crd {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
    background: #0b5ed7;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.card img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: The image **is** rounded. The difference between your result and the intended result is that the example photo has a different color whereas your image is the same white color  as the area around it.

Comment: It is working fine have you check by replacing other image as first image color is same as of your card background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image **is** rounded. The difference between your result and the intended result is that the example photo has a different color whereas your image is the same white color as the area around it.

In the following example, I only added three lines to your CSS to make the rounded image more apparent.

```
.card img {
    width: 76px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

hr {
    border: 1.5px solid #0b5ed7
}

.crd {
    background: #f1f2fa;
    transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
    background: #0b5ed7;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.card img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 76px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
<section class="bg-dark text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-white py-5">
        <h2 class="display-6">100's of Companies have Switched to Our Company</h2>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="card bg-light text-dark">
                      <img src="./assets/favicon-Icon Only [G]_76x76.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" />
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">John Doe</p>
                        <p>Sit occaecat amet aute duis occaecat irure ea. Nostrud minim aliqua esse amet. Culpa laborum voluptate culpa excepteur in in ullamco velit aliqua.
  
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-warning">
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                          <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
```